# How to Customize Youtube upload widget with javascript api

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am trying to make it so that the YouTube JavaScript API widget only allows for previously uploaded videos to be submitted to YouTube, is that possible? I have been looking over the YouTube API quite a bit and have not found any properties to let me do so. Is there a third party option that does that or do I need to dive deeper, then just use the widget and mess with the OAuth validation. I would greatly appreciate if someone could steer me in the right direction, especially if there are some working example that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Since Augst of 2012, using the Widget to upload an already existing video is no longer supported.

From the documentation:

> ...However, the option to upload an existing file is not currently
>   supported, so the widget always only displays an option to record and
>   upload a webcam video.

Here's [the complete documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_upload_widget).